# Questions regarding deploying visualforce pages to production

Tags: deployment, production

I’m new to Salesforce and this is my first project. My project requirement is about creating customer service related case through a Vf page on the case object. I’ve created two vf pages one for input (edit) and one for output display and one controller class. I’ve created a junction object which relates case object to an other custom object. I’ve process builders, workflows, approval process, sharing settings and reports involved in this project. I know basic method of deploying through the change sets. What points should I take into consideration before deploying. Do I need to write test classes, if so how many? Do I’ve to deploy profiles, junction obeject, sharing settings as well to the production or would they be replicated in production directly when I create/edit in dev sandbox. Please guide me. Pardon my ignorance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to write test classes, if so how many?

Yes, write unit tests for the controller. Use as many tests as you need to verify correct behavior. They can all be in one class.

> Do I’ve to deploy profiles, junction obeject, sharing settings as well to the production or would they be replicated in production directly when I create/edit in dev sandbox.

Nothing is created automatically. You will need to deploy all new and changed items. If you don't, your change set won't validate.

Deploying profiles is optional, but be aware if you don't, you will need to manually update security settings for the objects, fields, pages, etc.